# Top alignment in array environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays

I have an array which has a few columns, and each of the columns contains again an array. The problem is that the three arrays are vertically aligned with respect to the center. How to align them on the top?

Here is a simple example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{llll}
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
a& b& c\\
\hline
1&1&0\\1&2&3\\ 4 & 5& 6\\ \hline\end{array}&
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
a& b& c\\
\hline
1&3&4\\1&2&3\\  4&5&6\\ 7&9&8\\ \hline\end{array}&
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
a& b& c\\
\hline
1&2&5\\1&2&3\\ \hline\end{array}\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: Actual output]

but I would like to have something like this:

[image: Desired output]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `\begin{array}[t]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For each of the three inner `array` environments, you need to change

```
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
```

to

```
\begin{array}[t]{|l|l|l|}
```

Adding the `[t]` positioning specifier to the outer `array` doesn't hurt, but it doesn't do anything in particular either.

Comment: What if I want to have a right curly brace after one of the arrays? when I try that after adding "`[t]`", the brace becomes too tall, extending above the array.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever - Not sure I understand your comment. Please post a new question, in which you lay out in more detail what you're trying to achieve.